# SQLAlchemy+SQLite returns empty list for all queries

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, fastapi

When using the sample code from the FastAPI (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases), running queries on my local (pre-existing) SQLite Databases never returns any values (empty lists, count 0).

```
@app.get("/")
def root(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return get_all_podcasts(db)
```

```
# crud.py
def get_all_podcasts(db: Session, limit: int = 100):
    pods = db.query(Podcast).limit(limit).all()
    return pods
```

```
@dataclass
class Podcast(Base):
    __tablename__ = "podcasts"

    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    image: str

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    image = Column(String, index=True)

    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="podcast")
    drops = relationship("Drops", back_populates="podcast")
```

```
# database.py

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///podpill.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}, echo=True, echo_pool=True
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Logs:

```
2023-04-03 12:45:11,886 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-04-03 12:45:11,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT podcasts.id, podcasts.title, podcasts.description, podcasts.image 
FROM podcasts
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2023-04-03 12:45:11,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] (100, 0)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:61643 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2023-04-03 12:45:11,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

So far I've tried:

- Checking if the models fit
- Run create_engine in echo=True and checked the generated queries against the DB directly (which returns the expected results)
- [Using the newer 2.0 querying syntax](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#querying-2-0-style)

Everything to no avail. I'm almost to the point of manually running the queries without using an ORM, but wanted to at least try asking a question here.

For some reason even the PRAGMA queries run at startup return nothing

```
2023-04-03 12:47:23,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("podcasts")
2023-04-03 12:47:23,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-04-03 12:47:23,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("categories")
2023-04-03 12:47:23,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-04-03 12:47:23,705 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("drops")
2023-04-03 12:47:23,705 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

Thanks to [@python_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12502959/python-user) 's suggestion I changed the relative path to absolute and it worked.

I assume this is because the application is running inside Uvicorns ASGI server and this somehow messes with the paths.